# Are there any protocols equivalent to TLS?

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2

Are there any protocols equivalent to TLS that are used, and are they widely used and open for all people ?

or

The TLS is the only used to secure almost of the traffic available in the network?

I heard about another protocol that are developped by google equivalent to TLS that are name QUIC AND SPDY and I think is just used only by google ,use only udp and they are not available for all people.

Comment: SPDY is not “equivalent to TLS”, it is a kind of wrapper protocol around HTTP/HTTPS. And for example in Wikipedia you could have read, _“[f]or use within HTTPS, SPDY needs the TLS extension Next Protocol Negotiation (NPN)”_

Comment: TLS is itself a protocol to encrypt the communication channel. You have to relay on TLS if you like to have confidentiality in your communications.

Comment: The equivalent protocol at layer 2 and layer 3 is IPsec. All in all, IPsec has better security properties than TLS. IPsec can protect data lower in the protocol stack because it operates at layer 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

**SSH** could be seen as an alternative to **TLS**: both of them use cipher suites made of symetric and asymetric ciphers.

For instance, from an application point of view, to secure FTP connections, you can use:

- FTPS that gets its protection from **TLS** https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol_Secure
- SFTP that gets its protection from **SSH**
  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol